# Remove Cache-Control header set by JBoss EAP 6.3 in all responses

Tags: caching, jboss, http-headers, cache-control, jboss6.x

I'm using build Resteasy to build a RESTful Web Services API (and not using Infinispan cache system).

I've managed to add Cache-Control header with the desired value using **@Cache** annotation or modifying the **Response** object, but the problem is the header appears duplicated in the responses. There is always a **Cache-Control:no-cache** header which I can't remove.

The problem is not related with Resteasy or JAX-RS, it's JBoss itself who adds this header. I tried to use **filters** and **interceptors** to remove the Control-Cache header, but finally is always set with the no-cache value in the responses.

It seems JBoss adds this header to non public responses (secured requests). I've found some information about how to remove it in JBoss 7 or later versions, but I don't find the way to remove it in EAP 6.3.

*Mentioned resources:*

- *Manage cache-control header by setting in the Response object: [Jersey example](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/10/18/http-caching-with-jersey.html)*
- *Manage cache-control header by JAX-RS annotations:
  [RedHat doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/resteasy_reference_guide/cache_nocache_cachecontrol), [Concretepage example](http://%20%20%20https://www.concretepage.com/webservices/resteasy-3/jax-rs-resteasy-3-cache-and-nocache-annotations-example-for-cache-control)*
- *Solution for Wildly versions:    [JAX-RS REST service + EJB on WildFly 10, always adds no-cache HTTP header in responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396759/jax-rs-rest-service-ejb-on-wildfly-10-always-adds-no-cache-http-header-in-res), [RESTEasy - Response with duplicated Cache-Control - Wildfly10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138503/resteasy-response-with-duplicated-cache-control-wildfly10)*

Does anybody has an idea how to do solve it for JBoss 6.X?
Thanks in advance.